# How do I make one download link with two things to download?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, download

I know the normal download link is the a tag with the attribute of download and href, but that downloads only one thing. What if I want to make only one link for two things to download? Would there be 2 hrefs? Help please!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do is it have the anchor (link) tag call a javascript function.

```
<a href="#" onclick="Download()">Download</a>

function Download() {
    //javascript code to download first file - window.open("download link 1");
    ///javascript code to download second file - window.open("download link 2");
}
```